# CMake generator expression evaluated to "" instead of nothing

Tags: cmake

I'm using generator expressions in a custom command to compile hlsl shaders:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET Shaders
                           COMMAND vendor/shader-compiling/fxc.exe /nologo /Emain /Tvs_5_0 $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/Od> /Zi /Fo ${TARGET_SHADER_PATH}/hlsl/${FILE_WE}_vs.cso /Fd ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_WE}_vs.pdb ${TARGET_SHADER_PATH}/hlsl/${FILE_WE}_vs.hlsl
                           COMMAND vendor/shader-compiling/fxc.exe /nologo /Emain /Tps_5_0 $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/Od> /Zi /Fo ${TARGET_SHADER_PATH}/hlsl/${FILE_WE}_fs.cso /Fd ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_WE}_fs.pdb ${TARGET_SHADER_PATH}/hlsl/${FILE_WE}_fs.hlsl
                           MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${FILE}
                           WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                           COMMENT "Compiling HLSL shader ${TARGET_SHADER_PATH}/hlsl/${FILE_WE}.hlsl"
                           VERBATIM)
```

and in debug mode everything works fine.
However, in release mode, my expected result is the /Od flag does not get included in the command at all. However, what ended up happening is `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/Od>` gets evaluated to two double quotes and the command doesn't work.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody finds this useful, I solved the problem by adding `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` to my `add_custom_command` command. Not sure why that works but it does get rid of the empty pair of quotes in the middle of the command therefore the command works.

Comment: It works because it expanded an empty list to nothing. Every other element in your command is a one-element list so they expanded to itself.